# How to align svg rect and text to the left

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have SVG code in project but I am struggling with alignment.
This is my SVG code -

```
const svgImageOutBound = () => {
            return (
                `<svg width="240" height="18" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <rect width="16" height="16" rx="8" fill="#C938C4"/>
                    <text x="20" y="15" fill="#777">${i18n.label_out_bound_config_drift}</text>
                </svg>`
            );
        }
```

Using this inside the `div` code -

```
                `<div class="tooltip-header size-20">${
                        : d.configChangeType === "OUT_OF_BAND"
                        ? svgImageOutBound()
                        : i18n.label_in_bound_config_drift
                }</div>`
```

But this coming as center aligned -

[image]

Anyone faced this, please guide me..

Comment: The problem you have is that the aspect ratio of the svg element `width="240" height="18"` is not the same as the one of the viewBox: `viewBox="0 0 20 20"` Please try `viewBox="0 0 240 18"`

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the viewBox and width and it's working fine. please suggest if any better solution.

```
const svgImageOutBound = () => {
            return (
                `<svg width="240" height="18" viewBox="120 0 20 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <rect width="16" height="16" rx="8" fill="#C938C4"/>
                    <text x="24" y="15" fill="#777">${i18n.label_out_bound_config_drift}</text>
                </svg>`
            );
        }
```